# Using references in c++ to rename variables

Tags: c++, reference

I often work with complex mathematical expressions, like a long formula with a lot of variables. So, when I try to program it, in order to keep reasonable names for variables I have to do something like this:

```
double getCylinderVolume(double radius, double height){
    return 3.14 * radius * radius * height;
}
```

and it works well in this simple example.

The problem is that for a more complexe expressions the line with return statement may contain hundreds of characters, so the original formula is not readable any more.

Therefore, in order to avoid this, I thought about using references just to have variables with notations that are commonly used in maths. Like this:

```
double getCylinderVolume(double radius, double height){
    auto & R = radius;
    auto & h = height;
    return 3.14 * R * R * h;
}
```

so the final expression is much shorter compared to the previous example and you can easily see the formula.

Would it have any consequences in terms of performance?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: At least the performance question can be answered with a clear "No". https://godbolt.org/g/9fe1SF

Comment: You could break down the expression into smaller sub-expression and then return them ?

Comment: I agree with Baum, the performance definitely is worse. Every gigantic mathematical expression can be broken down into coherent building pieces. Put those into separate variables and don't worry, the compiler will most likely produce the same code.

Comment: Me, I have no problem with single character variable names in a context such as the specification of a function called `getCylinderVolume`. `r` and `h` are so widely used in the context of solid geometry to mean `radius` and `height` that the risk of misinterpretation is very small.  But this is an opinion, not really resolvable in the format of an SO Q&A.

Comment: @DeiDei: you write *I agree with Baum, the performance definitely is worse.* but Baum seems to state clearly that performance will be unaffected.

Comment: @DeiDei Indeed, as you can clearly see from the generated machine code, the performance is exactly the same.

Comment: @ Baum mit Augen, thank you very much for the link, it was exactly the thing I was looking for. It is good to know that compilers can optimise this kind of things. In my opinion, you can post it as an answer. Could you please specify in you answer that one have to use compiler optimisation to get the same performance. I checked in _compiler explorer_, to have the same assembly code you need to use at least **-O1**. Thanks also to all others for their feedback.

Comment: @Andrew26 it's common sense you need to compile with optimizations enabled if you care about performance. Although on the other side it's also true that maybe they don't teach this in school...

Comment: Even better, just use variables (preferably `const` ones), e.g. `const auto r = radius;` -- no need for references at all. The resulting assembly will be the same.

Comment: @bolov, I would mentioned optimisation just to make the answer complete...

Comment: @Andrew26 - A common baseline for discussing performance is "compile with optimizations". It kinda goes without saying when the question is about performance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is good that you are thinking about the readability of the formula, but I think you need to shift your focus.

Ideally when you look over a code base you should perfectly understand what a function does and where and how it is applicable **without looking at its implementation**.

What does this mean? Well a first good start is proper name. `getCylinderVolume` is a very good name. Just by the name you know all you need to know about the function (*).

But how about when that alone isn't enough? For instance when you have a very complex formula as you mentioned? Well get a good enough name and for the rest of the explanation supply **comments**. Describe what the function computes, what the parameters are and then post the mathematical formula. A link to a reliable online source for further mathematical explanations or for a project documentation page is a bonus. Most IDE's show the function comment (if properly positioned and formatted) at autocomplete suggestions. Furthermore there are tools (like doxygen) with which you can generate docs from source code and comments.

Inside the function you should comment the portions of the formula that you implemented differently (maybe due to optimizations) than the classical formula. E.g. a toy example: if the formula is `(a+b)/2` but you wrote `a + (b - a) / 2` to avoid overflow issues.

(*) well except the domain of the parameters, e.g. how does it behave if you supply negative or zero input?

---

Answering your actual question:

Yes, you are ok doing so (but add `const`). I don't see any problems with your approach. Any decent compiler worth it's salt would optimize both to the same assembly. For simple types (e.g. arithmetic types) you can even drop the reference and it would still be the same - performance wise. It becomes a matter of personal preference.

Although short non-descriptive names for variables (e.g. `r`) are frowned upon, I think it doesn't apply here, because the full name of the variable is easily available at the same scope. And the gains of making the formula more readable are worth here.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I agree that in this example one can use both: with or without the reference. Do you think it is still true for more complex types like cv::Mat from OpenCV or Eigen matrices?

Comment: @Andrew26 no. Those are types with costly copy operations. In that case definitely go with references. Again `const`

Comment: Ok, thank you once again!